# Add a gradient background using CSS

Tags: html, css

I decided to make something that would spin repeatedly on a gradient background. I've got the "spin repeatedly" part right, but the gradient background isn't working.

**HTML**:

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/gQioYac.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/gQioYac.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/gQioYac.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/gQioYac.png">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/gQioYac.png">
<div id="css-gradient"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
img {
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-play-state: running;
    float: left
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from { 
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

    #css-gradient {
        background: linear-gradient(blue, white)
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

I've also posted it as a fiddle so you can see it in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/ywtfsju1/

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Normally it is expected that you post the code in the post (though, adding a fiddle for convenience as well is perfectly fine). You don't need to press space repeatedly, you can select the code and press the `{}` icon in the editor, or press Ctrl-K and it will format as a code block for you. I have done that for you in this post, but in the future it will be much simpler if you format the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some mistakes with your brackets, here the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ywtfsju1/1/

`#css-gradient {` was in `@keyframes rotate {`, not it's after it.

You should use code indent to avoid such mistakes

Comment: Thanks for the code, but now the images are layering over the gradients, i've tried z-indexing and moving the code orders, it didn't work. jsfiddle for convenience https://jsfiddle.net/yw2me6oa/3/ i want to make it so the gradient is acting like a background for the pictures.